# How to nest and transclude this example with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I want make this code and I'm pretty sure that a different ng-transclude directive/service is needed, but I don't know how make it.

```
# controller.html
    <directive-folder-list>
        <generic-list-using-children-scope
          data="dataFromScopeWhereItIsPlaced" >
        <generic-list-using-children-scope>
    <directive-folder-list>
---
# directive-folder-list.html
    <directive-folder ng-repeat>
        <ng-transclude delegated-to-folder ></ng-transclude>
    <directive-folder>
    <!-- not in folder -->
    <ng-transclude data-using-this-scope ></ng-transclude>
---
# directive-folder.html
    <h1>title</h1>
    <ng-transclude data-using-this-scope ></ng-transclude>
```

The idea then is to use the "template" (directive "generic-list...") with the sources from each scope.
Anyone has a solution for this?